# Apply formulas and calculate inputted numbers from textboxes in a webform in c#

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox, calculation

I'm trying to create a program that calculates formulas in specific text boxes oninput, e.g total before and after tax. I get this when I try to add total of all textbox1,textbox2 and textbox3. This is what my test interface looklike
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z84KR.png)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


    function CalculateTotal(TextBox2) {
        var price = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        var tax = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
        var total = TextBox3.value.replace('%', '');
        var nothing = (price) + (tax) + (total);
        document.getElementById("TextBox4").value = nothing;
        document.getElementById("TextBox4").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and what is your question? you clicked a button "Ask Question" to create this post so you should probably ask something right?

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't asked anything:

`price`, `tax` and `total` are strings.

So `(price) + (tax) + (total);` concatenates those three strings.

You need to convert those strings into numbers if you want to do arrithmetic operations with them.

Read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

and pick the method that suits the number type you want to use.

Maybe you should use explicit typing until you are more familiar with C#.

```
string price = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
```

Would make things more obvious for you.

Comment: I always use explicit typing for primitive types. Implicit typing (`var`) is good when the type is obvious as in `var student = new Student();` and in cases where the type is complex like `IOrderedEnumerable<Grouping<TKey, TValue>>` as is often the case for LINQ results.